# Uncaught TypeError: mainApp.componet is not a function In interconnect communication of component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
mainApp.componet('myPane',{
    transclude:true,
    require:{
        tabsCtrl:'^myTabs'
    },
    bindings: {
      title: '@'
    },
    controller:function() {
      this.$onInit = function() {
        this.tabsCtrl.addPane(this);
        console.log(this);
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've a typo ...

it's not `componet`

but...

```
component
```

so for example:

```
mainApp.component('myPane',{
    transclude:true,
    require:{
        tabsCtrl:'^myTabs'
    },
    bindings: {
      title: '@'
    },
    controller:function() {
      this.$onInit = function() {
        this.tabsCtrl.addPane(this);
        console.log(this);
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'

});
```